# How to Check if Dependencies are Met Between RPM Packages?

Tags: rpm, packaging

Given a bunch of RPMs in a directory, how does one check whether
there are no unmet dependencies among them, and, if there are,
print a list of the missing ones?

The solution **should not assume anything about the architecture**
the packages are built for, except that it’s the same for all.

Comment: If RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, then `yum` will print what's missing : `# cd [rpm-folder] && yum install [package].rpm`.

Comment: *yum install [package].rpm* – That assumes that the packages can be installed on the current system which is too limiting.